# was not declared in this scope error in C++

Tags: c++, scope, makefile

I added one line in my below `getRecordForDay` method which is declaration of `AttributeMap` in my `.cc class file`.

And also I have already added the header for `AttributeMap` declaration as mentioned below.

```
#include "../../../nda/mpl/nydrecords/AttributeMap.hh"

// some code here

void getRecordForDay(string rowKey, vector<string> number, string columnFamily) {

    AttributeMap attr_map;

    // some code here

}
```

But still whenever I compile the above code, I always get error as -

`error: AttributeMap was not declared in this scope`

Any idea what wrong I am doing here?

Thanks..

Comment: is AtrributeMap declared in the same namespace?

Comment: Whenever I open AttributeMap.hh file, I can see AttributeMap class in that header file..!!

Comment: It could be that it's in another namespace (not the global one). And ideally, you don't want to specify the path to a file directly in your code. You want to add such info (generally termed include path) in your make file or project build settings.

Comment: To diagnose this error, we will need to see `AttributeMAp.hh`